# Can I simplify this any further? (multivariable limit)

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find $$\lim_{x,y\to 0,0} {xy^2+y^3\over x^2+y^4}$$
So I tried by using the y=mx line and got $\lim_{x,y\to 0,mx} {x(mx)^2+(mx)^3\over x^2+(mx)^4}$
which I simplified to: $$\lim_{x,y\to 0,mx} {m^2(1+m)\over 1+m^4x^2}$$
Does this mean the limit does not exist or I'm missing something else I can still do?

Thanks!

Comment: Since the limit depends on $m$ you have shown that the limit does **not** exist. The last limit should be written $\lim_{x \to 0} ...$ since you have picked a $y$ value.

Comment: You simplified wrong.

Comment: $\frac{x(m^2x^2)+m^3x^3}{x^2+m^4x^4}=\frac{xm^2+xm^3}{1+x^2m^4}=\frac{xm(1+m)}{1+x^2m^4}$

Comment: I don't see the mistake I made when simplifying...  Can you explain why it's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=(xy^2+y^3)/(x^2+y^4).$   Choosing any constant $m\ne 0$, you have  $$f(x,xm)=\frac {m^2(1+m)}{1+m^4x^2}$$  which tends to $$\frac {m^2(1+m)}{1+0}=m^2(1+m)$$ as $x\to 0.$ But $m^2(1+m)$ can be any real number, depending on the choice of $m.$  So there is no limit for $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0).$  For example, with $m=1$ we have $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x, x)=2$, but with $m=2$ we have  $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,2x)=12.$

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2+y^3}{x^2+y^4}.$$

we have

$\forall x\neq 0$

$$f(x,-x)=0$$ and

$$f(x^2,x)=\frac{x+1}{x}.$$

when $x \to 0$, we will have two limits.

we conclude that $\displaystyle{\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)} $ doesn't exist.